# Metric space and accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $E$ be a metric space such that every bounded subset of $E$ has a least one accumulation point. What can we say about $E$?

*Intuitively I know that $E$ is complete.* To prove this I must prove that for every Cauchy sequence its limit is in $E$. However I cannot combine the data above. Especially that *has at least one accumulation point* confuses me.

*May I have some hints?*

Comment: Pick a Cauchy sequence $\{a_n\}$. Then as a set $\{a_n\}$ is bounded and so has a accumulation point $a$. Now try to show $a_n \to a$.

Comment: Ok.. thank you... Must I invoke the definition? Shall I say that "suppose it does not converge to $a$, thus $|a_n-a|>\epsilon$ and get to something it is not true? "

Comment: You can do that, but it should also be possible to show that $a$ is the limit, by using the definition of a limit.

Comment: @Henrik The definition , as I know it, states that:

$$(\forall \epsilon >0) (\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{R})(n>n_0)\implies d(a_n, a)<\epsilon$$

How could I use that? Actually I feel that I'm missing something here...

Comment: Another hint: Let to find a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ of $\{a_n\}$ so that $a_{n_k} \to a$. Then (by the Cauchy property) show that also $a_n \to a$.

Comment: A subsequence? If I find a subsequence converging to $a$ then I'm done... ! But since $a_n$ is a Cauchy , that means that converges to $a$ since $a$ is an accumulation point... 

Also as a Cauchy sequence it clearly has a convergent subsequence going to $a$. Hence $a_n \rightarrow a$. No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already had been remarked in a comment, to show that $E$ is indeed complet, consider a Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$. Then the set $\{a_n\ |\ n\in\mathbb N\}$ is bounded and has an accumulation point $a$ by assumption. Thus, there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ converging to $a$. That means, for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $K\in\mathbb N$ such that $d(a_{n_k},a)<\varepsilon/2$ for each $k\geq K$. Moreover, since $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence we find some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $d(a_n,a_m)<\varepsilon/2$ for all $n,m\geq N$. Then $d(a_n,a)\leq d(a_n,a_{n_k})+d(a_{n_k},a)<\varepsilon$ for $n\geq\max\{N,K\}$. Note that $n_k\geq k$ for each $k\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: I guess I need a good night's sleep! It was easy.. thank you all...!! I got badly stuck at this question... and I note that it was not something diffucult at all...